# Creating a facet theme/design plot in ggplot2 without using facet_

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any possibility to create a facet_wrap looking plot in ggplot2 without using `facet_wrap()` The reason I would like to achieve this is to match some other design. In the plot `without_facet` below, can I somehow add "Setosa" in the top, so it looks like the `with_facet` plot, without using `facet_wrap`.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris[iris$Species == 'setosa', ]

with_facet <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() +facet_wrap(~Species)
with_facet

without_facet <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Would you like to get rid of the facet label on the plot or to combine different plots together?

Comment: So you provided an answer which was wrong, deleted it and decided to down vote my question?

Comment: i did not downvote and I don't think @desval did. It might be that your question is a bit unclear, no point second guessing. you might need to join plots using patchwork or gridExtra, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: How much do you want it to look like facet wrap? Do you want a frame around the heading with a background colour? Or is it OK just to have the heading at the top or above the plot area?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   ggtitle("setosa")  + 
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

A more "hackish"-one could be this hardcoded approach:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("setosa")  + 
  geom_rect(xmin = 4.225, xmax = 5.875 , ymin=4.5, ymax=4.6, fill ="lightgrey") + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', expand = 0.05) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12),
        plot.margin = margin(t = 30, r = 20, b = 20, l = 20, unit = "pt"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Paleolimbot answer on Gitbub (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2344)

```
element_textbox <- function(...) {
  el <- element_text(...)
  class(el) <- c("element_textbox", class(el))
  el
}

element_grob.element_textbox <- function(element, ...) {
  text_grob <- NextMethod()
  rect_grob <- element_grob(calc_element("strip.background", theme_bw()))

  ggplot2:::absoluteGrob(
    grid::gList(
      element_grob(calc_element("strip.background", theme_bw())),
      text_grob
    ),
    height = grid::grobHeight(text_grob), 
    width = grid::unit(1, "npc")
  )
}
```

From my original question, I added `theme_bw()`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- iris[iris$Species == 'setosa', ]

with_facet <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Species) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(color = 'black')) + theme_bw()

without_facet <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("setosa")  + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_textbox(
      hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t = 5, b = 5), size = 10
    ),
  )

grid.arrange(with_facet, without_facet)
```

[image]

Not identical, but works for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I had deleted it because it seemed no longer relevant after the original question was updated.

I am not sure I understand correctly. In case you want to arrange different plots together:

```
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(without_facet,
             without_facet,
             without_facet,
             without_facet, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: No sorry not what I want. Ive edited my question, hope it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This might be one option:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris[iris$Species == 'setosa', ]

# with annotate:


with_annotate <-
  ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() +
  annotate('text', x = 5, y = 4.7, label = "setosa", size = 12)

with_annotate

#or if you do not want the heading to print over the plot area

with_coord_cart <-
  ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() +
  annotate('text', x = 5, y = 4.7, label = "setosa", size = 8)+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2, 4.5), clip = 'off') +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(2, 1, 1, 1, "lines"))


with_coord_cart
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Comment: i think the header of the question is unambiguously saying: without using facet_