# How to add labels in a similar style to facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

This must be a simple solution, but I couldn't get my head around it. I have two methods "stage" (1,2,3 ) and "status" (pos, neg) and factor sex (female, male). I am generating two box_plots for each method and then combining both plots using ggarrange.

First, I want to label each graph as "status" and "stage", respectively.

I tried using facet_grid for labelling each plot individually but it will split the data.

Please find attach dummy data to illustrate my problem.

Many thanks for considering my request.

```
library(ggplot2)


size<-runif(12, min=20, max=40)
stage<-sample(0:3, 12, replace=TRUE)
status<-sample(x = c("pos", "neg"),size = 12, replace = TRUE) 
sex<-sample(x = c("Female", "Male"),size = 12, replace = TRUE) 
    
df <- data.frame(sex,stage,status,size)

#######Graph A##################
graph_A <- ggplot(df, aes(status, size, fill=sex)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
 # facet_grid(rows = vars(status), scales = "free")

#######Graph B##################
graph_B <- ggplot(df, aes(stage, size, fill=sex)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

#facet_grid(rows = vars(status), scales = "free")
graph_B

#######Graph A&B##################
figure_AB<-ggarrange(graph_A, graph_B, ncol=1, nrow=2, 
                    labels=c("a", "b"), 
                    common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top")
figure_AB
```

[I want to recreate this sort of labelling}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQCyZ.png)

Comment: `ggarrange` is a function in package `ggpubr`, not `gridExtra`. And you don't need to load packages `RColorBrewer` and `scales` to run your MWE. (The point is the *M* in MWE).

Comment: Hi Irene, your question is not "fully" clear. In particular, you might put us on the wrong track with using the term `facet`. Please note that you `label` the plots in your multiplot (using in your case `ggpubr::arrange()`). The label is a pointer for referencing. If you want to give your (sub-)plots a "header label" (name), you can use `ggplot`'s title layer. You either add a `+ ggtitle()` to your plot(s) or ` + labs(title = )`. You speak about breaking out your plots/data. Are you planning to use a `geom_facet()` layer? Or is the title what you are after?

Comment: Have you considered using `library(patchwork)`? It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it may be a nice work-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very "optimal" solution. But I manage to do what I was looking for by adding two variables to the df.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
size<-runif(12, min=20, max=40)
stage<-sample(0:3, 12, replace=TRUE)
status<-sample(x = c("pos", "neg"),size = 12, replace = TRUE) 
sex<-sample(x = c("Female", "Male"),size = 12, replace = TRUE) 
 
df <- data.frame(sex,stage,status,size)
df$stage_method<-"Stage method"
df$status_method<-"Status method"

graph_A <- ggplot(df, aes(status, size, fill=sex)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(status_method), scales = "free")


graph_B <- ggplot(df, aes(stage, size, fill=sex)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(stage_method), scales = "free")


figure_AB<-ggarrange(graph_A, graph_B, ncol=1, nrow=2, 
                    labels=c("a", "b"), 
                    common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top")
figure_AB
```

[image: now the labels are generated using facet_grid]

Comment: well done, Irene ... was about to attempt a similar hack.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following adding a "title"

```
size<-runif(12, min=20, max=40)
stage<-sample(0:3, 12, replace=TRUE)
status<-sample(x = c("pos", "neg"),size = 12, replace = TRUE) 
sex<-sample(x = c("Female", "Male"),size = 12, replace = TRUE) 

df <- data.frame(sex,stage,status,size)

#######Graph A##################
graph_A <- ggplot(df, aes(status, size, fill=sex)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
#--------------- add a label layer, i.e. title here
    labs(title = "status method")

#######Graph B##################
graph_B <- ggplot(df, aes(stage, size, fill=sex)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs(title = "stage method")

#facet_grid(rows = vars(status), scales = "free")
graph_B

#######Graph A&B##################
figure_AB <- ggpubr::ggarrange(graph_A, graph_B, ncol=1, nrow=2, 
                     labels=c("a", "b"), 
                     common.legend = TRUE, legend = "top")
figure_AB
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ray! Thanks for the reply I was looking for the style of labelling that comes out of facet_grid, to avoid using up space. I was thinking about some sort of annotation.

Comment: To emulate the `facet` styling this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610988/creating-a-facet-theme-design-plot-in-ggplot2-without-using-facet. In fact you want to now operate on (or better define your own) `theme()`. You can literally set all aspects/element of the graphical presentation. As mentioned in the other post - and to my knowledge - you emulate the facet-style. You may have to adapt and finetune this for different plots as certain dimensions of a plot relate to each other in terms of ratio of graphical/plot object units. Hope this gets you there!